# Finding a better scipy curve_fit! -- exponential function?

Tags: python, curve-fitting, exponential, scipy-optimize

I am trying to fit data using scipy curve_fit. I *believe* that negative exponential is probably best, as this works well for some of my other (similarly generated) data -- but I am achieving sub-optimal results.

I've normalized the dataset to avoid supplying initial values and am applying an exponential function as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
data = np.array([[0.32,0.38],[0.61,0.32],[0.28,0.50],[0.60,0.32],[0.26,0.45],[0.19,0.57],[0.61,0.32],[0.59,0.29],[0.39,0.42],[0.61,0.32],[0.20,0.46],[0.24,0.45],[0.59,0.29],[0.39,0.42],[0.56,0.39],[0.32,0.43],[0.38,0.44],[0.54,0.34],[0.61,0.32],[0.20,0.46],[0.28,0.51],[0.54,0.34],[0.60,0.32],[0.30,0.42],[0.28,0.43],[0.14,0.57],[0.24,0.54],[0.39,0.42],[0.20,0.56],[0.56,0.39],[0.24,0.54],[0.33,0.37],[0.33,0.51],[0.20,0.46],[0.32,0.39],[0.20,0.56],[0.19,0.57],[0.32,0.39],[0.30,0.42],[0.33,0.50],[0.54,0.34],[0.28,0.50],[0.32,0.39],[0.28,0.43],[0.27,0.42],[0.56,0.39],[0.19,0.57],[0.19,0.57],[0.60,0.32],[0.44,0.41],[0.27,0.42],[0.19,0.57],[0.24,0.38],[0.24,0.54],[0.61,0.32],[0.39,0.40],[0.30,0.41],[0.19,0.57],[0.14,0.57],[0.32,0.43],[0.14,0.57],[0.59,0.29],[0.44,0.41],[0.30,0.41],[0.32,0.38],[0.61,0.32],[0.20,0.46],[0.20,0.56],[0.30,0.41],[0.33,0.36],[0.14,0.57],[0.19,0.57],[0.46,0.38],[0.36,0.44],[0.61,0.32],[0.31,0.48],[0.60,0.32],[0.39,0.40],[0.14,0.57],[0.44,0.41],[0.24,0.49],[0.41,0.40],[0.19,0.57],[0.19,0.57],[0.31,0.49],[0.31,0.43],[0.35,0.35],[0.20,0.46],[0.54,0.34],[0.20,0.56],[0.39,0.44],[0.33,0.36],[0.20,0.56],[0.30,0.41],[0.56,0.39],[0.31,0.48],[0.28,0.51],[0.14,0.57],[0.61,0.32],[0.30,0.50],[0.20,0.56],[0.19,0.57],[0.59,0.31],[0.20,0.56],[0.27,0.42],[0.29,0.48],[0.56,0.39],[0.32,0.39],[0.20,0.56],[0.59,0.29],[0.24,0.49],[0.56,0.39],[0.60,0.32],[0.35,0.35],[0.28,0.50],[0.46,0.38],[0.14,0.57],[0.54,0.34],[0.32,0.38],[0.26,0.45],[0.26,0.45],[0.39,0.42],[0.19,0.57],[0.28,0.51],[0.27,0.42],[0.33,0.50],[0.54,0.34],[0.39,0.40],[0.19,0.57],[0.33,0.36],[0.22,0.44],[0.33,0.51],[0.61,0.32],[0.28,0.51],[0.25,0.50],[0.39,0.40],[0.34,0.35],[0.59,0.31],[0.31,0.49],[0.20,0.46],[0.39,0.46],[0.20,0.50],[0.32,0.39],[0.30,0.41],[0.23,0.44],[0.29,0.53],[0.28,0.50],[0.31,0.48],[0.61,0.32],[0.54,0.34],[0.28,0.53],[0.56,0.39],[0.19,0.57],[0.14,0.57],[0.59,0.29],[0.29,0.48],[0.44,0.41],[0.27,0.51],[0.50,0.29],[0.14,0.57],[0.60,0.32],[0.32,0.39],[0.19,0.57],[0.24,0.38],[0.56,0.39],[0.14,0.57],[0.54,0.34],[0.61,0.38],[0.27,0.53],[0.20,0.46],[0.61,0.32],[0.27,0.42],[0.27,0.42],[0.20,0.56],[0.30,0.41],[0.31,0.51],[0.32,0.39],[0.31,0.51],[0.29,0.48],[0.20,0.46],[0.33,0.51],[0.31,0.43],[0.30,0.41],[0.27,0.44],[0.31,0.51],[0.29,0.48],[0.35,0.35],[0.46,0.38],[0.28,0.51],[0.61,0.38],[0.31,0.49],[0.33,0.51],[0.59,0.29],[0.14,0.57],[0.31,0.51],[0.39,0.40],[0.32,0.39],[0.20,0.56],[0.55,0.31],[0.56,0.39],[0.24,0.49],[0.56,0.39],[0.27,0.50],[0.60,0.32],[0.54,0.34],[0.19,0.57],[0.28,0.51],[0.54,0.34],[0.56,0.39],[0.19,0.57],[0.59,0.31],[0.37,0.45],[0.19,0.57],[0.44,0.41],[0.32,0.43],[0.35,0.48],[0.24,0.49],[0.26,0.45],[0.14,0.57],[0.59,0.30],[0.26,0.45],[0.26,0.45],[0.14,0.57],[0.20,0.50],[0.31,0.45],[0.27,0.51],[0.30,0.41],[0.19,0.57],[0.30,0.41],[0.27,0.50],[0.34,0.35],[0.30,0.42],[0.27,0.42],[0.27,0.42],[0.34,0.35],[0.35,0.35],[0.14,0.57],[0.45,0.36],[0.26,0.45],[0.56,0.39],[0.34,0.35],[0.19,0.57],[0.30,0.41],[0.19,0.57],[0.26,0.45],[0.26,0.45],[0.59,0.29],[0.19,0.57],[0.26,0.45],[0.32,0.39],[0.30,0.50],[0.28,0.50],[0.32,0.39],[0.59,0.29],[0.32,0.51],[0.56,0.39],[0.59,0.29],[0.61,0.38],[0.33,0.51],[0.22,0.44],[0.33,0.36],[0.27,0.42],[0.20,0.56],[0.28,0.51],[0.31,0.48],[0.20,0.56],[0.61,0.32],[0.24,0.54],[0.59,0.29],[0.32,0.43],[0.61,0.32],[0.19,0.57],[0.61,0.38],[0.55,0.31],[0.19,0.57],[0.31,0.46],[0.32,0.52],[0.30,0.41],[0.28,0.51],[0.28,0.50],[0.60,0.32],[0.61,0.32],[0.27,0.50],[0.59,0.29],[0.41,0.47],[0.39,0.42],[0.20,0.46],[0.19,0.57],[0.14,0.57],[0.23,0.47],[0.54,0.34],[0.28,0.51],[0.19,0.57],[0.33,0.37],[0.46,0.38],[0.27,0.42],[0.20,0.56],[0.39,0.42],[0.30,0.47],[0.26,0.45],[0.61,0.32],[0.61,0.38],[0.35,0.35],[0.14,0.57],[0.35,0.35],[0.28,0.51],[0.61,0.32],[0.24,0.54],[0.54,0.34],[0.28,0.43],[0.24,0.54],[0.30,0.41],[0.56,0.39],[0.23,0.52],[0.14,0.57],[0.26,0.45],[0.30,0.42],[0.32,0.43],[0.19,0.57],[0.45,0.36],[0.27,0.42],[0.29,0.48],[0.28,0.43],[0.27,0.51],[0.39,0.44],[0.32,0.49],[0.24,0.49],[0.56,0.39],[0.20,0.56],[0.30,0.42],[0.24,0.38],[0.46,0.38],[0.28,0.50],[0.26,0.45],[0.27,0.50],[0.23,0.47],[0.39,0.42],[0.28,0.51],[0.24,0.49],[0.27,0.42],[0.26,0.45],[0.60,0.32],[0.32,0.43],[0.39,0.42],[0.28,0.50],[0.28,0.52],[0.61,0.32],[0.32,0.39],[0.24,0.50],[0.39,0.40],[0.33,0.36],[0.24,0.38],[0.54,0.33],[0.19,0.57],[0.61,0.32],[0.33,0.36],[0.19,0.57],[0.30,0.41],[0.19,0.57],[0.34,0.35],[0.24,0.42],[0.27,0.42],[0.54,0.34],[0.54,0.34],[0.24,0.49],[0.27,0.42],[0.56,0.39],[0.19,0.57],[0.20,0.50],[0.14,0.57],[0.30,0.41],[0.30,0.41],[0.33,0.36],[0.26,0.45],[0.26,0.45],[0.23,0.47],[0.32,0.39],[0.27,0.53],[0.30,0.41],[0.20,0.46],[0.34,0.35],[0.34,0.35],[0.14,0.57],[0.46,0.38],[0.27,0.42],[0.36,0.44],[0.17,0.51],[0.60,0.32],[0.27,0.42],[0.20,0.56],[0.24,0.49],[0.41,0.40],[0.61,0.38],[0.19,0.57],[0.28,0.50],[0.23,0.52],[0.61,0.32],[0.39,0.46],[0.33,0.51],[0.19,0.57],[0.39,0.44],[0.56,0.39],[0.35,0.35],[0.28,0.43],[0.54,0.34],[0.36,0.44],[0.14,0.57],[0.61,0.38],[0.46,0.38],[0.61,0.32],[0.19,0.57],[0.54,0.34],[0.27,0.53],[0.33,0.51],[0.31,0.51],[0.59,0.29],[0.24,0.42],[0.28,0.43],[0.56,0.39],[0.28,0.50],[0.61,0.32],[0.29,0.48],[0.20,0.46],[0.50,0.29],[0.56,0.39],[0.20,0.50],[0.24,0.38],[0.32,0.39],[0.32,0.43],[0.28,0.50],[0.22,0.44],[0.20,0.56],[0.27,0.42],[0.61,0.38],[0.31,0.49],[0.20,0.46],[0.27,0.42],[0.24,0.38],[0.61,0.32],[0.26,0.45],[0.23,0.44],[0.59,0.30],[0.56,0.39],[0.33,0.44],[0.27,0.42],[0.31,0.51],[0.27,0.53],[0.32,0.39],[0.28,0.51],[0.30,0.42],[0.46,0.38],[0.27,0.42],[0.30,0.47],[0.39,0.40],[0.28,0.43],[0.30,0.42],[0.32,0.39],[0.59,0.31],[0.36,0.44],[0.54,0.34],[0.34,0.35],[0.30,0.41],[0.32,0.49],[0.32,0.43],[0.31,0.51],[0.32,0.52],[0.60,0.32],[0.19,0.57],[0.41,0.47],[0.32,0.39],[0.28,0.43],[0.28,0.51],[0.32,0.51],[0.56,0.39],[0.24,0.45],[0.55,0.31],[0.24,0.43],[0.61,0.38],[0.33,0.51],[0.30,0.41],[0.32,0.47],[0.32,0.38],[0.33,0.51],[0.39,0.40],[0.19,0.57],[0.27,0.42],[0.54,0.33],[0.59,0.29],[0.28,0.51],[0.61,0.38],[0.19,0.57],[0.30,0.41],[0.14,0.57],[0.32,0.39],[0.34,0.35],[0.54,0.34],[0.24,0.54],[0.56,0.39],[0.24,0.49],[0.61,0.32],[0.61,0.38],[0.61,0.32],[0.19,0.57],[0.14,0.57],[0.54,0.34],[0.59,0.29],[0.28,0.43],[0.19,0.57],[0.61,0.32],[0.32,0.43],[0.29,0.48],[0.56,0.39],[0.19,0.57],[0.56,0.39],[0.59,0.29],[0.59,0.29],[0.59,0.30],[0.14,0.57],[0.23,0.44],[0.28,0.50],[0.29,0.48],[0.31,0.45],[0.27,0.51],[0.24,0.45],[0.61,0.38],[0.24,0.49],[0.14,0.57],[0.61,0.32],[0.39,0.40],[0.33,0.44],[0.54,0.33],[0.33,0.51],[0.20,0.50],[0.19,0.57],[0.25,0.50],[0.28,0.43],[0.17,0.51],[0.19,0.57],[0.27,0.42],[0.20,0.56],[0.24,0.38],[0.19,0.57],[0.28,0.50],[0.28,0.50],[0.27,0.42],[0.26,0.45],[0.39,0.42],[0.23,0.47],[0.28,0.43],[0.32,0.39],[0.32,0.39],[0.24,0.54],[0.33,0.36],[0.29,0.53],[0.27,0.42],[0.44,0.41],[0.27,0.42],[0.33,0.36],[0.24,0.43],[0.61,0.38],[0.20,0.50],[0.55,0.31],[0.31,0.46],[0.60,0.32],[0.30,0.41],[0.41,0.47],[0.39,0.40],[0.27,0.53],[0.61,0.38],[0.46,0.38],[0.28,0.43],[0.44,0.41],[0.35,0.35],[0.24,0.49],[0.31,0.43],[0.27,0.42],[0.61,0.38],[0.29,0.48],[0.54,0.34],[0.61,0.32],[0.20,0.56],[0.24,0.49],[0.39,0.40],[0.27,0.42],[0.59,0.29],[0.59,0.29],[0.19,0.57],[0.24,0.54],[0.59,0.31],[0.24,0.38],[0.33,0.51],[0.23,0.44],[0.20,0.46],[0.24,0.45],[0.29,0.48],[0.28,0.50],[0.61,0.32],[0.19,0.57],[0.22,0.44],[0.19,0.57],[0.39,0.44],[0.19,0.57],[0.28,0.50],[0.30,0.41],[0.44,0.41],[0.28,0.52],[0.28,0.43],[0.54,0.33],[0.28,0.50],[0.19,0.57],[0.14,0.57],[0.30,0.41],[0.26,0.45],[0.56,0.39],[0.27,0.51],[0.20,0.46],[0.24,0.38],[0.32,0.38],[0.26,0.45],[0.61,0.32],[0.59,0.29],[0.19,0.57],[0.43,0.45],[0.14,0.57],[0.35,0.35],[0.56,0.39],[0.34,0.35],[0.19,0.57],[0.56,0.39],[0.27,0.42],[0.19,0.57],[0.60,0.32],[0.24,0.54],[0.54,0.34],[0.61,0.38],[0.33,0.51],[0.27,0.42],[0.32,0.39],[0.34,0.35],[0.20,0.56],[0.26,0.45],[0.32,0.51],[0.33,0.51],[0.35,0.35],[0.31,0.43],[0.56,0.39],[0.59,0.29],[0.28,0.43],[0.30,0.42],[0.27,0.44],[0.28,0.53],[0.29,0.48],[0.33,0.51],[0.60,0.32],[0.54,0.33],[0.19,0.57],[0.33,0.49],[0.30,0.41],[0.54,0.34],[0.27,0.53],[0.19,0.57],[0.19,0.57],[0.32,0.39],[0.20,0.56],[0.35,0.35],[0.30,0.42],[0.46,0.38],[0.54,0.34],[0.54,0.34],[0.14,0.57],[0.33,0.51],[0.32,0.39],[0.14,0.57],[0.59,0.29],[0.59,0.31],[0.30,0.41],[0.26,0.45],[0.32,0.38],[0.32,0.39],[0.59,0.31],[0.20,0.56],[0.20,0.46],[0.29,0.48],[0.59,0.29],[0.39,0.40],[0.28,0.50],[0.32,0.39],[0.28,0.53],[0.44,0.41],[0.20,0.50],[0.24,0.49],[0.20,0.46],[0.28,0.52],[0.24,0.50],[0.32,0.43],[0.39,0.40],[0.38,0.44],[0.60,0.32],[0.54,0.33],[0.61,0.32],[0.19,0.57],[0.59,0.29],[0.33,0.49],[0.28,0.43],[0.24,0.38],[0.30,0.41],[0.27,0.51],[0.35,0.48],[0.61,0.32],[0.43,0.45],[0.20,0.50],[0.24,0.49],[0.20,0.50],[0.20,0.56],[0.29,0.48],[0.14,0.57],[0.14,0.57],[0.26,0.45],[0.26,0.45],[0.39,0.40],[0.33,0.36],[0.56,0.39],[0.59,0.29],[0.27,0.42],[0.35,0.35],[0.30,0.41],[0.20,0.50],[0.19,0.57],[0.29,0.48],[0.39,0.42],[0.37,0.45],[0.30,0.41],[0.20,0.56],[0.30,0.42],[0.41,0.47],[0.28,0.43],[0.14,0.57],[0.27,0.53],[0.32,0.39],[0.30,0.41],[0.34,0.35],[0.32,0.47],[0.33,0.51],[0.20,0.56],[0.56,0.39],[0.60,0.32],[0.28,0.52],[0.56,0.39],[0.44,0.41],[0.27,0.42],[0.00,1.00],[0.29,0.49],[0.89,0.06],[0.22,0.66],[0.18,0.70],[0.67,0.22],[0.14,0.79],[0.58,0.17],[0.67,0.12],[0.95,0.05],[0.46,0.26],[0.15,0.54],[0.16,0.67],[0.48,0.31],[0.41,0.29],[0.18,0.66],[0.10,0.71],[0.11,0.72],[0.65,0.15],[0.94,0.03],[0.17,0.67],[0.44,0.29],[0.32,0.38],[0.79,0.10],[0.52,0.26],[0.25,0.59],[0.89,0.04],[0.69,0.13],[0.43,0.34],[0.75,0.07],[0.16,0.65],[0.02,0.70],[0.38,0.33],[0.57,0.23],[0.75,0.07],[0.25,0.58],[0.94,0.02],[0.55,0.22],[0.58,0.17],[0.14,0.79],[0.20,0.56],[0.10,0.88],[0.15,0.79],[0.11,0.77],[0.67,0.22],[0.07,0.87],[0.43,0.33],[0.08,0.84],[0.05,0.67],[0.07,0.77],[0.17,0.68],[1.00,0.00],[0.15,0.79],[0.08,0.77],[0.16,0.67],[0.69,0.13],[0.07,0.87],[0.15,0.54],[0.55,0.19],[0.14,0.63],[0.75,0.18],[0.25,0.63],[0.83,0.05],[0.55,0.50],[0.86,0.04],[0.73,0.18],[0.44,0.32],[0.70,0.15],[0.89,0.06],[0.17,0.67],[0.61,0.12],[0.55,0.50],[0.36,0.56],[0.03,0.86],[0.09,0.82],[0.09,0.82],[0.09,0.83],[0.17,0.68],[0.88,0.03],[0.64,0.22],[0.08,0.85],[0.74,0.16],[0.47,0.28],[0.05,0.84],[0.14,0.54],[0.01,0.93],[0.77,0.16],[0.17,0.60],[0.64,0.22],[0.84,0.05],[0.85,0.03],[0.23,0.67],[0.20,0.69],[0.00,0.87],[0.14,0.77],[0.11,0.69],[0.17,0.67],[0.56,0.27],[0.14,0.67],[0.37,0.31],[0.11,0.69],[0.35,0.52],[0.53,0.27],[0.50,0.21],[0.25,0.64],[0.36,0.56],[0.39,0.26],[0.02,0.83],[0.41,0.29],[0.07,0.77],[0.16,0.63],[0.92,0.03],[0.10,0.71],[0.83,0.05],[0.42,0.27],[0.62,0.12],[0.23,0.60],[0.19,0.61],[0.69,0.19],[0.21,0.65],[0.67,0.19],[0.18,0.69],[0.44,0.29],[0.14,0.65],[0.73,0.18],[0.15,0.66],[0.44,0.34],[0.74,0.10],[0.18,0.69],[0.25,0.61],[0.52,0.23],[0.06,0.82],[0.52,0.29],[0.22,0.68],[0.46,0.26],[0.14,0.54],[0.78,0.07],[0.80,0.05],[0.15,0.67],[0.10,0.82],[0.56,0.27],[0.64,0.22],[0.87,0.06],[0.14,0.66],[0.10,0.84],[0.88,0.05],[0.02,0.81],[0.62,0.15],[0.13,0.68],[0.50,0.28],[0.11,0.62],[0.46,0.32],[0.56,0.28],[0.43,0.28],[0.12,0.83],[0.11,0.80],[0.10,0.83],[0.90,0.04],[0.17,0.65],[0.15,0.63],[0.72,0.15],[0.64,0.26],[0.84,0.06],[0.09,0.83],[0.16,0.68],[0.09,0.63],[0.43,0.29],[0.88,0.05],[0.20,0.69],[0.73,0.09],[0.61,0.20],[0.67,0.13],[0.08,0.85],[0.73,0.16],[0.89,0.05],[0.41,0.25],[0.61,0.23],[0.58,0.22],[0.03,0.84],[0.58,0.24],[0.48,0.30],[0.25,0.54],[0.23,0.63],[0.41,0.46],[0.84,0.06],[0.45,0.29],[0.09,0.55],[0.54,0.26],[0.11,0.82],[0.69,0.18],[0.43,0.45],[0.43,0.28],[0.45,0.32],[0.07,0.78],[0.26,0.64],[0.92,0.04],[0.12,0.66],[0.32,0.51],[0.28,0.59],[0.70,0.18]])

x = data[:,0]
y = data[:,1]

def func(x,a,b,c):
    return a * np.exp(-b*x) + c

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y)
a, b, c = popt

x_line = np.arange(min(x), max(x), 0.01)
x_line =np.reshape(x_line,(-1,1))

y_line = func(x_line, a, b, c)
y_line = np.reshape(y_line,(-1,1))

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.plot(x_line,y_line)

plt.show()
```

As you can see, the fit deviates towards high x values. [example plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1jr3.png) I know there are numerous similar questions out there, and I have read many - but my math skills are not phenomenal so i am struggling coming up with a better solution for my particular problem.

I'm not tied to the exponential function - can anyone suggest something better?
I need to do this semi-automatically for hundreds of datasets, so ideally I want something as flexible as possible.

Any help greatly appreciated!

p.s. I am sorry about posting such a large sample dataset - but I figured this kind of question necessitates the actual data, and I didn't want to post links to suspicious looking files.. =)

Comment: Just to understand why you see this effect: Your data seems to not be evenly distributed along the x axis (you can see this by running `plt.hist(x)`, which will show you the count of points for several values of x). Intuitively, this will offset the fit because it is similar to saying that points with smaller x values are more important than points with higher x values for the data you provided.

Comment: thanks @LoW =), i am aware that its not distributed evenly - but i thought that the curve-fit was not affected by varying point densities as much as it is... is there some way of weighting the x values to remove this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an optimal solution, but this should work for any kind of density distribution in your data. The idea is to resample the data a given number of times by computing local averages along the x-axis to have evenly distributed points.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3.6
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def my_floor(a, precision=0):
    return np.round(a - 0.5 * 10**(-precision), precision)

data = np.array([[0.32,0.38],[0.61,0.32],[0.28,0.50],[0.60,0.32],[0.26,0.45],[0.19,0.57],[0.61,0.32],[0.59,0.29],[0.39,0.42],[0.61,0.32],[0.20,0.46],[0.24,0.45],[0.59,0.29],[0.39,0.42],[0.56,0.39],[0.32,0.43],[0.38,0.44],[0.54,0.34],[0.61,0.32],[0.20,0.46],[0.28,0.51],[0.54,0.34],[0.60,0.32],[0.30,0.42],[0.28,0.43],[0.14,0.57],[0.24,0.54],[0.39,0.42],[0.20,0.56],[0.56,0.39],[0.24,0.54],[0.33,0.37],[0.33,0.51],[0.20,0.46],[0.32,0.39],[0.20,0.56],[0.19,0.57],[0.32,0.39],[0.30,0.42],[0.33,0.50],[0.54,0.34],[0.28,0.50],[0.32,0.39],[0.28,0.43],[0.27,0.42],[0.56,0.39],[0.19,0.57],[0.19,0.57],[0.60,0.32],[0.44,0.41],[0.27,0.42],[0.19,0.57],[0.24,0.38],[0.24,0.54],[0.61,0.32],[0.39,0.40],[0.30,0.41],[0.19,0.57],[0.14,0.57],[0.32,0.43],[0.14,0.57],[0.59,0.29],[0.44,0.41],[0.30,0.41],[0.32,0.38],[0.61,0.32],[0.20,0.46],[0.20,0.56],[0.30,0.41],[0.33,0.36],[0.14,0.57],[0.19,0.57],[0.46,0.38],[0.36,0.44],[0.61,0.32],[0.31,0.48],[0.60,0.32],[0.39,0.40],[0.14,0.57],[0.44,0.41],[0.24,0.49],[0.41,0.40],[0.19,0.57],[0.19,0.57],[0.31,0.49],[0.31,0.43],[0.35,0.35],[0.20,0.46],[0.54,0.34],[0.20,0.56],[0.39,0.44],[0.33,0.36],[0.20,0.56],[0.30,0.41],[0.56,0.39],[0.31,0.48],[0.28,0.51],[0.14,0.57],[0.61,0.32],[0.30,0.50],[0.20,0.56],[0.19,0.57],[0.59,0.31],[0.20,0.56],[0.27,0.42],[0.29,0.48],[0.56,0.39],[0.32,0.39],[0.20,0.56],[0.59,0.29],[0.24,0.49],[0.56,0.39],[0.60,0.32],[0.35,0.35],[0.28,0.50],[0.46,0.38],[0.14,0.57],[0.54,0.34],[0.32,0.38],[0.26,0.45],[0.26,0.45],[0.39,0.42],[0.19,0.57],[0.28,0.51],[0.27,0.42],[0.33,0.50],[0.54,0.34],[0.39,0.40],[0.19,0.57],[0.33,0.36],[0.22,0.44],[0.33,0.51],[0.61,0.32],[0.28,0.51],[0.25,0.50],[0.39,0.40],[0.34,0.35],[0.59,0.31],[0.31,0.49],[0.20,0.46],[0.39,0.46],[0.20,0.50],[0.32,0.39],[0.30,0.41],[0.23,0.44],[0.29,0.53],[0.28,0.50],[0.31,0.48],[0.61,0.32],[0.54,0.34],[0.28,0.53],[0.56,0.39],[0.19,0.57],[0.14,0.57],[0.59,0.29],[0.29,0.48],[0.44,0.41],[0.27,0.51],[0.50,0.29],[0.14,0.57],[0.60,0.32],[0.32,0.39],[0.19,0.57],[0.24,0.38],[0.56,0.39],[0.14,0.57],[0.54,0.34],[0.61,0.38],[0.27,0.53],[0.20,0.46],[0.61,0.32],[0.27,0.42],[0.27,0.42],[0.20,0.56],[0.30,0.41],[0.31,0.51],[0.32,0.39],[0.31,0.51],[0.29,0.48],[0.20,0.46],[0.33,0.51],[0.31,0.43],[0.30,0.41],[0.27,0.44],[0.31,0.51],[0.29,0.48],[0.35,0.35],[0.46,0.38],[0.28,0.51],[0.61,0.38],[0.31,0.49],[0.33,0.51],[0.59,0.29],[0.14,0.57],[0.31,0.51],[0.39,0.40],[0.32,0.39],[0.20,0.56],[0.55,0.31],[0.56,0.39],[0.24,0.49],[0.56,0.39],[0.27,0.50],[0.60,0.32],[0.54,0.34],[0.19,0.57],[0.28,0.51],[0.54,0.34],[0.56,0.39],[0.19,0.57],[0.59,0.31],[0.37,0.45],[0.19,0.57],[0.44,0.41],[0.32,0.43],[0.35,0.48],[0.24,0.49],[0.26,0.45],[0.14,0.57],[0.59,0.30],[0.26,0.45],[0.26,0.45],[0.14,0.57],[0.20,0.50],[0.31,0.45],[0.27,0.51],[0.30,0.41],[0.19,0.57],[0.30,0.41],[0.27,0.50],[0.34,0.35],[0.30,0.42],[0.27,0.42],[0.27,0.42],[0.34,0.35],[0.35,0.35],[0.14,0.57],[0.45,0.36],[0.26,0.45],[0.56,0.39],[0.34,0.35],[0.19,0.57],[0.30,0.41],[0.19,0.57],[0.26,0.45],[0.26,0.45],[0.59,0.29],[0.19,0.57],[0.26,0.45],[0.32,0.39],[0.30,0.50],[0.28,0.50],[0.32,0.39],[0.59,0.29],[0.32,0.51],[0.56,0.39],[0.59,0.29],[0.61,0.38],[0.33,0.51],[0.22,0.44],[0.33,0.36],[0.27,0.42],[0.20,0.56],[0.28,0.51],[0.31,0.48],[0.20,0.56],[0.61,0.32],[0.24,0.54],[0.59,0.29],[0.32,0.43],[0.61,0.32],[0.19,0.57],[0.61,0.38],[0.55,0.31],[0.19,0.57],[0.31,0.46],[0.32,0.52],[0.30,0.41],[0.28,0.51],[0.28,0.50],[0.60,0.32],[0.61,0.32],[0.27,0.50],[0.59,0.29],[0.41,0.47],[0.39,0.42],[0.20,0.46],[0.19,0.57],[0.14,0.57],[0.23,0.47],[0.54,0.34],[0.28,0.51],[0.19,0.57],[0.33,0.37],[0.46,0.38],[0.27,0.42],[0.20,0.56],[0.39,0.42],[0.30,0.47],[0.26,0.45],[0.61,0.32],[0.61,0.38],[0.35,0.35],[0.14,0.57],[0.35,0.35],[0.28,0.51],[0.61,0.32],[0.24,0.54],[0.54,0.34],[0.28,0.43],[0.24,0.54],[0.30,0.41],[0.56,0.39],[0.23,0.52],[0.14,0.57],[0.26,0.45],[0.30,0.42],[0.32,0.43],[0.19,0.57],[0.45,0.36],[0.27,0.42],[0.29,0.48],[0.28,0.43],[0.27,0.51],[0.39,0.44],[0.32,0.49],[0.24,0.49],[0.56,0.39],[0.20,0.56],[0.30,0.42],[0.24,0.38],[0.46,0.38],[0.28,0.50],[0.26,0.45],[0.27,0.50],[0.23,0.47],[0.39,0.42],[0.28,0.51],[0.24,0.49],[0.27,0.42],[0.26,0.45],[0.60,0.32],[0.32,0.43],[0.39,0.42],[0.28,0.50],[0.28,0.52],[0.61,0.32],[0.32,0.39],[0.24,0.50],[0.39,0.40],[0.33,0.36],[0.24,0.38],[0.54,0.33],[0.19,0.57],[0.61,0.32],[0.33,0.36],[0.19,0.57],[0.30,0.41],[0.19,0.57],[0.34,0.35],[0.24,0.42],[0.27,0.42],[0.54,0.34],[0.54,0.34],[0.24,0.49],[0.27,0.42],[0.56,0.39],[0.19,0.57],[0.20,0.50],[0.14,0.57],[0.30,0.41],[0.30,0.41],[0.33,0.36],[0.26,0.45],[0.26,0.45],[0.23,0.47],[0.32,0.39],[0.27,0.53],[0.30,0.41],[0.20,0.46],[0.34,0.35],[0.34,0.35],[0.14,0.57],[0.46,0.38],[0.27,0.42],[0.36,0.44],[0.17,0.51],[0.60,0.32],[0.27,0.42],[0.20,0.56],[0.24,0.49],[0.41,0.40],[0.61,0.38],[0.19,0.57],[0.28,0.50],[0.23,0.52],[0.61,0.32],[0.39,0.46],[0.33,0.51],[0.19,0.57],[0.39,0.44],[0.56,0.39],[0.35,0.35],[0.28,0.43],[0.54,0.34],[0.36,0.44],[0.14,0.57],[0.61,0.38],[0.46,0.38],[0.61,0.32],[0.19,0.57],[0.54,0.34],[0.27,0.53],[0.33,0.51],[0.31,0.51],[0.59,0.29],[0.24,0.42],[0.28,0.43],[0.56,0.39],[0.28,0.50],[0.61,0.32],[0.29,0.48],[0.20,0.46],[0.50,0.29],[0.56,0.39],[0.20,0.50],[0.24,0.38],[0.32,0.39],[0.32,0.43],[0.28,0.50],[0.22,0.44],[0.20,0.56],[0.27,0.42],[0.61,0.38],[0.31,0.49],[0.20,0.46],[0.27,0.42],[0.24,0.38],[0.61,0.32],[0.26,0.45],[0.23,0.44],[0.59,0.30],[0.56,0.39],[0.33,0.44],[0.27,0.42],[0.31,0.51],[0.27,0.53],[0.32,0.39],[0.28,0.51],[0.30,0.42],[0.46,0.38],[0.27,0.42],[0.30,0.47],[0.39,0.40],[0.28,0.43],[0.30,0.42],[0.32,0.39],[0.59,0.31],[0.36,0.44],[0.54,0.34],[0.34,0.35],[0.30,0.41],[0.32,0.49],[0.32,0.43],[0.31,0.51],[0.32,0.52],[0.60,0.32],[0.19,0.57],[0.41,0.47],[0.32,0.39],[0.28,0.43],[0.28,0.51],[0.32,0.51],[0.56,0.39],[0.24,0.45],[0.55,0.31],[0.24,0.43],[0.61,0.38],[0.33,0.51],[0.30,0.41],[0.32,0.47],[0.32,0.38],[0.33,0.51],[0.39,0.40],[0.19,0.57],[0.27,0.42],[0.54,0.33],[0.59,0.29],[0.28,0.51],[0.61,0.38],[0.19,0.57],[0.30,0.41],[0.14,0.57],[0.32,0.39],[0.34,0.35],[0.54,0.34],[0.24,0.54],[0.56,0.39],[0.24,0.49],[0.61,0.32],[0.61,0.38],[0.61,0.32],[0.19,0.57],[0.14,0.57],[0.54,0.34],[0.59,0.29],[0.28,0.43],[0.19,0.57],[0.61,0.32],[0.32,0.43],[0.29,0.48],[0.56,0.39],[0.19,0.57],[0.56,0.39],[0.59,0.29],[0.59,0.29],[0.59,0.30],[0.14,0.57],[0.23,0.44],[0.28,0.50],[0.29,0.48],[0.31,0.45],[0.27,0.51],[0.24,0.45],[0.61,0.38],[0.24,0.49],[0.14,0.57],[0.61,0.32],[0.39,0.40],[0.33,0.44],[0.54,0.33],[0.33,0.51],[0.20,0.50],[0.19,0.57],[0.25,0.50],[0.28,0.43],[0.17,0.51],[0.19,0.57],[0.27,0.42],[0.20,0.56],[0.24,0.38],[0.19,0.57],[0.28,0.50],[0.28,0.50],[0.27,0.42],[0.26,0.45],[0.39,0.42],[0.23,0.47],[0.28,0.43],[0.32,0.39],[0.32,0.39],[0.24,0.54],[0.33,0.36],[0.29,0.53],[0.27,0.42],[0.44,0.41],[0.27,0.42],[0.33,0.36],[0.24,0.43],[0.61,0.38],[0.20,0.50],[0.55,0.31],[0.31,0.46],[0.60,0.32],[0.30,0.41],[0.41,0.47],[0.39,0.40],[0.27,0.53],[0.61,0.38],[0.46,0.38],[0.28,0.43],[0.44,0.41],[0.35,0.35],[0.24,0.49],[0.31,0.43],[0.27,0.42],[0.61,0.38],[0.29,0.48],[0.54,0.34],[0.61,0.32],[0.20,0.56],[0.24,0.49],[0.39,0.40],[0.27,0.42],[0.59,0.29],[0.59,0.29],[0.19,0.57],[0.24,0.54],[0.59,0.31],[0.24,0.38],[0.33,0.51],[0.23,0.44],[0.20,0.46],[0.24,0.45],[0.29,0.48],[0.28,0.50],[0.61,0.32],[0.19,0.57],[0.22,0.44],[0.19,0.57],[0.39,0.44],[0.19,0.57],[0.28,0.50],[0.30,0.41],[0.44,0.41],[0.28,0.52],[0.28,0.43],[0.54,0.33],[0.28,0.50],[0.19,0.57],[0.14,0.57],[0.30,0.41],[0.26,0.45],[0.56,0.39],[0.27,0.51],[0.20,0.46],[0.24,0.38],[0.32,0.38],[0.26,0.45],[0.61,0.32],[0.59,0.29],[0.19,0.57],[0.43,0.45],[0.14,0.57],[0.35,0.35],[0.56,0.39],[0.34,0.35],[0.19,0.57],[0.56,0.39],[0.27,0.42],[0.19,0.57],[0.60,0.32],[0.24,0.54],[0.54,0.34],[0.61,0.38],[0.33,0.51],[0.27,0.42],[0.32,0.39],[0.34,0.35],[0.20,0.56],[0.26,0.45],[0.32,0.51],[0.33,0.51],[0.35,0.35],[0.31,0.43],[0.56,0.39],[0.59,0.29],[0.28,0.43],[0.30,0.42],[0.27,0.44],[0.28,0.53],[0.29,0.48],[0.33,0.51],[0.60,0.32],[0.54,0.33],[0.19,0.57],[0.33,0.49],[0.30,0.41],[0.54,0.34],[0.27,0.53],[0.19,0.57],[0.19,0.57],[0.32,0.39],[0.20,0.56],[0.35,0.35],[0.30,0.42],[0.46,0.38],[0.54,0.34],[0.54,0.34],[0.14,0.57],[0.33,0.51],[0.32,0.39],[0.14,0.57],[0.59,0.29],[0.59,0.31],[0.30,0.41],[0.26,0.45],[0.32,0.38],[0.32,0.39],[0.59,0.31],[0.20,0.56],[0.20,0.46],[0.29,0.48],[0.59,0.29],[0.39,0.40],[0.28,0.50],[0.32,0.39],[0.28,0.53],[0.44,0.41],[0.20,0.50],[0.24,0.49],[0.20,0.46],[0.28,0.52],[0.24,0.50],[0.32,0.43],[0.39,0.40],[0.38,0.44],[0.60,0.32],[0.54,0.33],[0.61,0.32],[0.19,0.57],[0.59,0.29],[0.33,0.49],[0.28,0.43],[0.24,0.38],[0.30,0.41],[0.27,0.51],[0.35,0.48],[0.61,0.32],[0.43,0.45],[0.20,0.50],[0.24,0.49],[0.20,0.50],[0.20,0.56],[0.29,0.48],[0.14,0.57],[0.14,0.57],[0.26,0.45],[0.26,0.45],[0.39,0.40],[0.33,0.36],[0.56,0.39],[0.59,0.29],[0.27,0.42],[0.35,0.35],[0.30,0.41],[0.20,0.50],[0.19,0.57],[0.29,0.48],[0.39,0.42],[0.37,0.45],[0.30,0.41],[0.20,0.56],[0.30,0.42],[0.41,0.47],[0.28,0.43],[0.14,0.57],[0.27,0.53],[0.32,0.39],[0.30,0.41],[0.34,0.35],[0.32,0.47],[0.33,0.51],[0.20,0.56],[0.56,0.39],[0.60,0.32],[0.28,0.52],[0.56,0.39],[0.44,0.41],[0.27,0.42],[0.00,1.00],[0.29,0.49],[0.89,0.06],[0.22,0.66],[0.18,0.70],[0.67,0.22],[0.14,0.79],[0.58,0.17],[0.67,0.12],[0.95,0.05],[0.46,0.26],[0.15,0.54],[0.16,0.67],[0.48,0.31],[0.41,0.29],[0.18,0.66],[0.10,0.71],[0.11,0.72],[0.65,0.15],[0.94,0.03],[0.17,0.67],[0.44,0.29],[0.32,0.38],[0.79,0.10],[0.52,0.26],[0.25,0.59],[0.89,0.04],[0.69,0.13],[0.43,0.34],[0.75,0.07],[0.16,0.65],[0.02,0.70],[0.38,0.33],[0.57,0.23],[0.75,0.07],[0.25,0.58],[0.94,0.02],[0.55,0.22],[0.58,0.17],[0.14,0.79],[0.20,0.56],[0.10,0.88],[0.15,0.79],[0.11,0.77],[0.67,0.22],[0.07,0.87],[0.43,0.33],[0.08,0.84],[0.05,0.67],[0.07,0.77],[0.17,0.68],[1.00,0.00],[0.15,0.79],[0.08,0.77],[0.16,0.67],[0.69,0.13],[0.07,0.87],[0.15,0.54],[0.55,0.19],[0.14,0.63],[0.75,0.18],[0.25,0.63],[0.83,0.05],[0.55,0.50],[0.86,0.04],[0.73,0.18],[0.44,0.32],[0.70,0.15],[0.89,0.06],[0.17,0.67],[0.61,0.12],[0.55,0.50],[0.36,0.56],[0.03,0.86],[0.09,0.82],[0.09,0.82],[0.09,0.83],[0.17,0.68],[0.88,0.03],[0.64,0.22],[0.08,0.85],[0.74,0.16],[0.47,0.28],[0.05,0.84],[0.14,0.54],[0.01,0.93],[0.77,0.16],[0.17,0.60],[0.64,0.22],[0.84,0.05],[0.85,0.03],[0.23,0.67],[0.20,0.69],[0.00,0.87],[0.14,0.77],[0.11,0.69],[0.17,0.67],[0.56,0.27],[0.14,0.67],[0.37,0.31],[0.11,0.69],[0.35,0.52],[0.53,0.27],[0.50,0.21],[0.25,0.64],[0.36,0.56],[0.39,0.26],[0.02,0.83],[0.41,0.29],[0.07,0.77],[0.16,0.63],[0.92,0.03],[0.10,0.71],[0.83,0.05],[0.42,0.27],[0.62,0.12],[0.23,0.60],[0.19,0.61],[0.69,0.19],[0.21,0.65],[0.67,0.19],[0.18,0.69],[0.44,0.29],[0.14,0.65],[0.73,0.18],[0.15,0.66],[0.44,0.34],[0.74,0.10],[0.18,0.69],[0.25,0.61],[0.52,0.23],[0.06,0.82],[0.52,0.29],[0.22,0.68],[0.46,0.26],[0.14,0.54],[0.78,0.07],[0.80,0.05],[0.15,0.67],[0.10,0.82],[0.56,0.27],[0.64,0.22],[0.87,0.06],[0.14,0.66],[0.10,0.84],[0.88,0.05],[0.02,0.81],[0.62,0.15],[0.13,0.68],[0.50,0.28],[0.11,0.62],[0.46,0.32],[0.56,0.28],[0.43,0.28],[0.12,0.83],[0.11,0.80],[0.10,0.83],[0.90,0.04],[0.17,0.65],[0.15,0.63],[0.72,0.15],[0.64,0.26],[0.84,0.06],[0.09,0.83],[0.16,0.68],[0.09,0.63],[0.43,0.29],[0.88,0.05],[0.20,0.69],[0.73,0.09],[0.61,0.20],[0.67,0.13],[0.08,0.85],[0.73,0.16],[0.89,0.05],[0.41,0.25],[0.61,0.23],[0.58,0.22],[0.03,0.84],[0.58,0.24],[0.48,0.30],[0.25,0.54],[0.23,0.63],[0.41,0.46],[0.84,0.06],[0.45,0.29],[0.09,0.55],[0.54,0.26],[0.11,0.82],[0.69,0.18],[0.43,0.45],[0.43,0.28],[0.45,0.32],[0.07,0.78],[0.26,0.64],[0.92,0.04],[0.12,0.66],[0.32,0.51],[0.28,0.59],[0.70,0.18]])

x = data[:,0]
y = data[:,1]

#---------------------------ADD THIS---------------------------

# Define how to resample the data 
n_bins = 20 # choose how many samples to use 
bin_size = (max(x) - min(x))/n_bins

# Prepare empty arrays for resampled x and y 
x_res, y_res = [],[] 

# Resample the data with consistent density 
for i in range(n_bins-1): 
    lower = x >= min(x)+i*bin_size
    higher = x < min(x)+(i+1)*bin_size
    x_res.append(np.mean(x[np.where(lower & higher)]))
    y_res.append(np.mean(y[np.where(lower & higher)]))

#------------------------------------------------------

def func(x,a,b,c):
    return a * np.exp(-b*x) + c

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x_res, y_res)
a, b, c = popt

x_line = np.arange(min(x), max(x), 0.01)
x_line = np.reshape(x_line,(-1,1))

y_line = func(x_line, a, b, c)
y_line = np.reshape(y_line,(-1,1))

plt.scatter(x,y,alpha=0.5)
plt.scatter(x_res, y_res)
plt.plot(x_line,y_line, c='red')

plt.show()
```

Which gives the output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks LoW - this is a nice solution. I am wondering about getting the same results by combining your binning idea with the sigma parameter as suggested by piterbarg below

Answer (score 1):

`curve_fit` does not give you a great deal of control over the fit, you may want to look at the much more general, but somewhat more complicated to use, `least_squares`:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html

where you can control a lot of things. `curve_fit` does give you a `sigma` parameter which allows you to weight the 'uncertainty' in your points. The trick here is to assign lower uncertainty to the points around `x=1` where the fit is poor. By giving it lower uncertainty the fitter will try harder to fit them.

after some experimenting, if replacing your `...curve_fit...` line with

```
uncertainty = np.exp(-5*x*x)
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y, sigma = uncertainty)
```

I got the following fit
[image: better fit]

you can try to improve this by playing with the `uncertainty` vector above

Comment: Ah i was not aware of the sigma parameter.. thank you! I imagine i could combine your solution with LoW's above and assign uncertainty based on the number of points in each 'bin' -like LoW suggested.

Comment: @agator yes you could, definitely. That would be more scientific then choosing `sigma` until the fit 'looks right', for sure